# What is mean by 'char const * const c=" " '

Tags: c, pointers, constants, variable-declaration

```
char const*const variablename = " ";
```

what does it mean?

is it same as pointer declaration?

Please anyone explain.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: const always goes to the item immediately to its *left* unless it is the lead decl, in which case it is the first item to its right. I.e. `const char *` and `char const *` are the same. That said, this is a const pointer to const char data variable called `variablename` that is initialized (and always will be) to a read-only char string consisting of one space and one null-terminator.

Comment: This question has been asked many times before; see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890535/what-is-the-difference-between-char-const-and-const-char http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949254/const-char-const-versus-const-char http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851436/difference-between-const-char-char-const-const-char-const-string-storage etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a `const` pointer to a `const` C string. This means that neither the contents of the string, nor the pointer itself, can be changed.

Comment: normally when should we use this ?

Comment: @NPE Because of you I didn't sleep last night :D

Answer (score 3):

> const *protects his left side*, unless there is nothing to his left and
>   **only then** it protects his right side.

Applying this to your example, it's a **`const` pointer to a `const` `String`**.