# How do I pass a pointer of a string argument to a function?

Tags: c

The argv array is a list pointers, each pointing to the respective argument, with the first element the number of command line arguments, correct?

My question is how do I pass a string argument to a function? In this small example I'm just trying to print the text I write as argument in the command line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void ptest(char *);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    ptest(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}

void ptest(char *ptr)
{
    printf("%s\n", ptr);
}
```

This code does not compile. It gives the following compilation errors:

```
teste2.c:8:8: warning: passing 'const char *' to parameter of type 'char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
        ptest(argv[1]);
              ^~~~~~~
teste2.c:4:18: note: passing argument to parameter here
void ptest(char *);
             ^
```

Comment: is there something wrong with your code?

Comment: Yes, it does not compile. Ok, I'll add that detail

Comment: This is a warning message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not you issue.  Your issue is that you've added the `const` keyword, meaning that you have a pointer to an array of values, where the array of values can't be changed.

You can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851436/difference-between-const-char-char-const-const-char-const-string-storage) for a better explanation.

In your code:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
```

remove the `const` and your code will compile:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Comment: Removing the `const` is fine but consider changing `ptest` to accept a `const char *` instead.