# const char * VS char const * const (Not about what is const)

Tags: c, string, constants

So, I know the differences between char const *, char * const, and char const * const. Those being:

> char* the_string : I can change the char to which the_string points,
>   and I can modify the char at which it points.
>
> const char* the_string : I can change the char to which the_string
>   points, but I cannot modify the char at which it points.
>
> char* const the_string : I cannot change the char to which the_string
>   points, but I can modify the char at which it points.
>
> const char* const the_string : I cannot change the char to which
>   the_string points, nor can I modify the char at which it points.

(from [const char * const versus const char *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949254/const-char-const-versus-const-char))

Now, my question is: Let's say I'm writing a function that would not modify the C string that is passed to it, for example:

```
int countA(??? string) {
    int count = 0;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<strlen(string); i++) {
         if (string[i] == 'A') count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Now, what should the header be?

```
int countA(char const * string); 
int countA(char const * const string);
```

My feeling is that I should use the second one, because I'm not going to modify the pointer itself, neither the contents of the array. But when I look to the header of standard functions they use the first one. Example

```
char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source );
```

Why?

(In fact `char const *` doesn't really make sense to me, because if you're thinking about the abstract string, either you are not modifying the string (so, `char const * const` because you are not modifying the pointer, neither the contents) or you will modify the string (so just `char *` because, you may modify the contents and you may need to allocate more memory, so you may need to modify the pointer)

I hope someone can make all this clear to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, it does not matter whether the pointer itself is const or not, because it is passed by-value anyway: Whatever `strcpy` does to `source` will not affect the caller's variable, because `strcpy` will operate on a copy of the caller's `source` on the stack, not the original. Note I am talking about the *pointer value*, not what the pointer points *to*, which should obviously *not* be changed since it is the *source* parameter.

```
char dest[10];
char const * source = "Hello";
strcpy( dest, source );
// no matter what strcpy does, the value of source will be unchanged
```

Within `strcpy`, you need to iterate pointers over the arrays pointed to by `destination` and `source` anyway. Not declaring the parameters as const allows the function to use the values from the stack directly, without copying / casting them first.

Answer (score 5):

Having `const char *` **represents a contract**. It's a promise the function will not use that pointer to modify the contents passed by the user. Whether the pointer itself is constant or not is less valuable.

So, for the caller, whether the pointer itself is `const` or not makes no difference whatsoever.

In many implementations "string" functions regularly modify the passed pointer without modifying the contents. If the spec (the C standard) would mandate the pointer itself to be constant, **it would be a limiting factor** for all implementations, without providing any benefit for the caller.

---

As a side note, I think you shouldn't make everything `const` and then work your way around it. Just make stuff `const` if it *feels* the function shouldn't have reason to change it. In short, don't go const-mad, **it's not a silver bullet** and *can* be a recipe for frustration.

Answer (score 3):

The non-defining declarations:

```
int countA(char const * string);
int countA(char const * const string);
int countA(char const * foobar);
int countA(char const *);
```

are all equivalent. The `string` parameter names (in effect) a local variable inside the implementation of `countA`. It's none of the caller's business whether the implementation modifies that variable or not, and it doesn't affect the signature of the function.

It is the caller's business whether the function modifies the *referand* of `string`, so the first const is important. It is slightly the caller's business what the variable is named, but only because the convention is to name parameters in declarations as a hint what they're used for. Documentation is the way to *completely* convey the meaning of each parameter, not its name.

If you want a rule: omit the second `const`, because it clutters the declaration while telling the caller nothing of any use.

You could include it in the function *definition*, but there are some problems with doing so. You either need to keep the header up to date with the definition (in which case you'll sometimes find yourself changing the header due to a change in implementation details that doesn't affect callers). Or else you have to accept that the header doesn't match the definition, which will occasionally upset people who see:

```
int countA(char const * const string) {
    return 0; 
}
```

and search the headers for `int countA(char const * const string)`, or vice-versa see the header and search the source. They need a smarter search term.

Comment: I didn't know the second `const` actually does *not* affect the signature!

Comment: @DevSolar: Yep. I'm too lazy to look it up in the standard, but IIRC there's explicit text to say so.

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a function parameter as `const char * const`, it is not different to your callers from `const char *`: they could not care less what you do with that pointer, because to them it is all "pass by value" anyway.

The second `const` is there for you, not for your users. If you know that you are not going to modify that pointer, then by all means declare it `const char * const`: it is going to help you and others who maintain your code to catch errors later.

As for the standard library, my guess is that they did not want to make it `const char * const` because they wanted an ability to modify the poitners:

```
char * strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source ) {
    char *res = destination;
    while (*destination++ = *source++)
        ;
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- `char const *s` : `s` is a pointer to `const char`.
- `char *const s` : `s` is a constant pointer to `char`.

When `s` is a function parameter, the first notation is more useful than the second.

- With `char const *`, you can't modify the pointed value.
- With `char *const`, you can't modify the value of your pointer. It is like `int const` in function parameters : you can't do operations directly onto your parameter. It doesn't change anything for the call function. (now, it's almost useless for the compiler, but it's meaningful for programmers)

Comment: Actually, a *good* programmer in this case would know that `s` is passed by value anyway so the `const` does not matter either way...

Comment: Of course ; as I said, it doesn't change anything for the call function, so it's just use in an expressive way (as an aid to the compiler's optimizer). It's like integer constants in parameters, some programmers use it (me too).

Comment: But what is `const char* const*` ?