# Error LNK2019 and Fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I know my question and its answer exist anywhere on site but, I have more than it.

I have zip library and use it in another C++ project.

Zip library:
    **czip.h**

```
#ifndef _CZIP_H_
#define _CZIP_H_

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sys\stat.h>

#include <stdio.h>


#ifndef DLL_INTERNAL
#define DLL_INTERNAL __declspec( dllimport )
#endif 

class DLL_INTERNAL CZipException
{
public:
CZipException( const char*fm, ... );
const char* GetString() { return m_sMessage; }
protected:
char m_sMessage[ 128 ];
};


// pure virtual
class DLL_INTERNAL CMamaZip
{
public:
CMamaZip( const char *sSourceFileName );
void SwapSize( const char *sTargetFileName );
protected:
virtual int HardWork( int inFile, int outFile ) = 0;

char m_sSourceFileName[ MAX_PATH ];
char *m_sOperation;
};


class DLL_INTERNAL CZip : public CMamaZip
{
 public:
CZip( const char *sSourceFileName );
 protected:
virtual int HardWork( int inFile, int outFile );
};


class DLL_INTERNAL CUnzip : public CMamaZip
{
 public:
CUnzip( const char *sSourceFileName );
 protected:
virtual int HardWork( int inFile, int outFile );
};

#endif // _CZIP_H_
```

**czip.cpp:**

```
#define DLL_INTERNAL __declspec( dllexport )
#include "czip.h"
#include "tailor.h"


// global variables instancied in gzip 
extern "C" {

extern int dozip( int, int);
extern int dounzip( int, int );
extern long time_stamp;
extern char ifname[MAX_PATH_LEN]; 
extern int save_orig_name;

extern int ifd;
extern int ofd;

} 

int inFile, outFile;

// this function is called by gzip when there is an error
// instead of doing an exit( .. )
extern "C" void do_exit_dll(int exitcode)
{
close( inFile );
close( outFile );
throw( CZipException( "problem with zipping/unzipping operation : %d", exitcode ) );    
}  



CZipException::CZipException( const char* fm, ... )
{
char *p = m_sMessage;
va_list args;
va_start( args, fm );
p += vsprintf( p, fm, args);
va_end( args );
}


int WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
return 1;
} 



CMamaZip::CMamaZip( const char *sUnzippedFileName )
{
strcpy( m_sSourceFileName, sUnzippedFileName );
}


// throw CZipException
void CMamaZip::SwapSize( const char *sTargetFileName )
{

if (strcmp(m_sSourceFileName,sTargetFileName)==0)
    throw ( CZipException( "target name must be different than source name" ) );

// try to open in unzipped file
if ( ( inFile = open( m_sSourceFileName, _O_BINARY | _O_RDONLY ) ) == -1 )
    throw ( CZipException( "unable to open source file" ) );

if ( ( outFile = open( sTargetFileName, _O_BINARY | _O_RDWR | _O_CREAT | _O_EXCL , _S_IREAD | _S_IWRITE  ) ) == -1 )
{
    close(inFile);
    throw ( CZipException( "unable to create target file" ) );
}

ifd=inFile; ofd=outFile;
int ret = HardWork( inFile, outFile );

close( inFile );
close( outFile );

if (ret != 0)
    throw( CZipException( "problem while %s file", m_sOperation ) );
  }


 CZip::CZip( const char* sSourceFileName )
: CMamaZip( sSourceFileName ) 

 { 
m_sOperation = "zipping";   
strcpy( ifname, m_sSourceFileName );
save_orig_name = 1;
 }


 CUnzip::CUnzip( const char* sSourceFileName )
: CMamaZip( sSourceFileName ) 

 { 
m_sOperation = "unzipping";     
 }

 int CUnzip::HardWork( int inFile, int outFile )
 {
return dounzip( inFile, outFile );
 }


 int CZip::HardWork( int inFile, int outFile )
 {
return dozip( inFile, outFile );
 }
```

Output conf. type of this zip project is **static library(.lib)**

I built this project and got zipdll.lib file.

And in another project, I set necessary configurations like that additional library vs.

and include header file. Finally my code is;

```
 #include "czip.h"
 #pragma comment(lib, "zipdll")
 . 
 .
 .
 CZip oZip(sourceFile);
 oZip.SwapSize(targetFile);
```

When I built project, I got these errors;

```
  1>c:\users\16481min\desktop\czip_demo\main.cpp(91): warning C4101: 'e' : unreferenced local variable
  1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall CMamaZip::SwapSize(char const *)" (__imp_?SwapSize@CMamaZip@@QAEXPBD@Z)
  1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall CZip::CZip(char const *)" (__imp_??0CZip@@QAE@PBD@Z)
  1>.\Debug\test_zip.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
  ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What is the problem? What I have to do?
Any help?

**EDIT:**

Main function:

```
#include "czip.h"
#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "wininet")
#pragma comment(lib, "zipdll")


typedef char OSC;

using namespace std;
void ZipSend(OSC *directory, OSC *ftpServerAddr, OSC *ftpUsername, OSC *ftpPassword);

 int main()
 {

try 
{     
 ZipSend("C:\\Users\\16481MIN\\Desktop\\Foto","10.100.47.23","ftptestuser","abcd+1234");
}
catch( CZipException e )
{
    return -1;
}
return 0;
  }

  void ZipSend(OSC *directory, OSC *ftpServerAddr, OSC *ftpUsername, OSC *ftpPassword)
  {
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
HANDLE hFind;

OSC pattern[MAX_PATH];
    OSC sourceFile[MAX_PATH];
OSC targetFile[MAX_PATH];

memset(pattern, 0x00, MAX_PATH);
sprintf(pattern,"%s\\*.*", directory);

hFind = FindFirstFile(pattern, &FindFileData);
if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
{
} 
else 
{
    do
    {
        if(_tcscmp(FindFileData.cFileName, TEXT("."))==0 || _tcscmp(FindFileData.cFileName, TEXT(".."))==0)
            continue;

        if(FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {

        }
        else
        {
             memset(sourceFile, 0x00, sizeof(sourceFile));
             memset(targetFile, 0x00, sizeof(targetFile));

             string strSourceFile(FindFileData.cFileName);
             int lastindex = strSourceFile.find_last_of("."); 
             string strTargetFile(strSourceFile.substr(0, lastindex));

             sprintf(sourceFile,"%s\\%s", directory, strSourceFile.c_str());
             sprintf(targetFile, "%s\\%s.zip", directory, strTargetFile.c_str());

             try 
             {

                CZip oZip(sourceFile);
                oZip.SwapSize(targetFile);

             }
             catch( CZipException e )
             {
             }
             try 
             {
                 OSC ftpFilePath[MAX_PATH] = "";
                 strcat(ftpFilePath, "/hobim/ASYADAN/");
                 strcat(ftpFilePath, strTargetFile.c_str());
                 strcat(ftpFilePath, ".zip");

             }
             catch(exception e)
             {

             }


        }
    }
    while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData));
    FindClose(hFind);
}
   }
```

Comment: The linker isn't finding your .lib file. I'd guess that either you've given the wrong path or you haven't added any directories where to look for libs.

Comment: No, I gave the right path to linker, I am sure of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the exporting as DLL from your header file:

```
#ifndef DLL_INTERNAL
#define DLL_INTERNAL __declspec( dllimport )
#endif
```

will specify `DLL_INTERNAL` as being something that this library will want to **import** from another library. This goes in client (the one app using the library) code. In your library code you need

```
#ifndef DLL_INTERNAL
#define DLL_INTERNAL __declspec( dllexport )
#endif
```

to specify these methods will go **out** from this library.

But generally, these are taken care by the MSVS framework where the application is compiled with a specific define to tell whether it is the library being compiled (where it needs to use `dllexport`) or the client (where it needs to use `dllimport`)

So a full export/import macro looks like:

```
#ifndef DLL_COMPILED
#define DLL_INTERNAL __declspec( dllexport )
else
#define DLL_INTERNAL __declspec( dllimport )
#endif
```

and you need to take care that `DLL_COMPILED` is being specified in the compilation phase (as a parameter to the compiler, usually with `/DDLL_COMPILED`) of the library.

Answer (score 1):

The linker is looking for `CMamaZip::SwapSize(char const *)`   input  - `char const *`
and in czip.h the method is - 
`SwapSize( const char *sTargetFileName )` with input -  `const char *`

Comment: I posted at the end of question.

Comment: Or change the input of those methods. A good explenation regarding `const char*` vs `char const*` is in - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949254/const-char-const-versus-const-char)