# error: could not convert 'p1' from 'Person (*)()' to 'Person'

Tags: c++

I get

```
error: could not convert 'p1' from 'Person (*)()' to 'Person'
```

whenever i use the default constructor (when i create Person p1), i know it's because i'm using a char array but i have to use it, i can't use strings

i'm also getting 2 warnings

```
warning: converting to non-pointer type 'char' from NULL [-Wconversion-null]|
```

in the default constructor

```
warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]|
```

when i create Person p2

so here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class Person{
   private:
    char* name;
    char gender;
    int age;
   public:
    Person();
    Person(char*, char, int);
    friend void printInfo(Person);
};

Person::Person()
:name(NULL), gender(NULL), age(0) // this results in the first warning
{
}
Person::Person(char* n, char g, int a)
:name(n), gender(g), age(a)
{
}
void printInfo(Person p){
 cout << "Name: " << p.name << endl;
 cout << "Age: " << p.age << endl;
 cout << "Gender: " << p.gender << endl;
}

int main()
{
Person p1(); // this results in an error
printInfo(p1);

Person p2("Max", 'm', 18); // this results in the second warning
printInfo(p2);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're running into the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

`Person p1();` declares a function called `p1` which returns a `Person` and takes no arguments.  If you want to default construct a `Person` object called `p1` simply say `Person p1;`

Answer (score 2):

First warning comes because you try to assign NULL to gender which is a char.

Second one is because you assign const char pointer to a non-const char pointer in your object. Using `char const *` (or `const char*`) as your pointer type is one of the ways to get rid of this warning. Using char* const will not help, because it basically means const pointer to a modifyable string (i.e. you cannot change the pointer but you can change the string) which is not the case when you give it a string constant.

Comment: ok i solved the first warning, but i don't know what to do in the second one, if i make the char* const i still get the same error

Comment: char* const and char const* are two different things, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949254/const-char-const-versus-const-char