# const char* still modifies the pointed value

Tags: c, char, constants

Why is the value pointed by a `const char*` being updated by a char array that should just hold a copy of the original string literal that should be stored in the ROM.

I know the basic theory of `const char*`, `char* const`, `const char* const` from this link [const char * const versus const char *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949254/const-char-const-versus-const-char)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    char a[] = "ABCD";
    char z[] = "WXYZ";
    const char* b = a;
    a[1] = 'N';  // WHY THIS WORKS AND UPDATES THE VALUE IN B.... a should make its own copy of ABCD and update
                 // it to NBCD... b should still point to a read only memory ABCD which can't be changed4

    //b[1] = 'N'; // THIS FAILS AS DESIRED
    printf("%s\n", b);   // Output -> ANCD

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are no copies of arrays in your program. Assignment doesn't copy arrays.

Answer (score 4):

```
const char* b = a;
```

`const` here means you can't modify what the pointer points through `b`, that's it. It's still legal to modify the content through `a`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing to understand is what is a simple pointer. When you write

```
const char* b = a;
```

It says variable b points to same memory location of variable a. So whatever change you make in a will reflect in  memory pointed by b too.

Answer (score 0):

You made `b` a pointer-to-const, so you can not modify values pointed at by `b` using `b[...]`. However you did not make `a` a const-pointer and you can modify the `a[]` contents.

Variable `b` keeps what you have assigned. And you assigned a pointer to the first item of `a` array. Now `b` points at the same memory location where `a[0]` is stored. Once you modified `a` array contents, you see that `b` points at the same location, containing modified data now.

Answer (score 0):

C only prohibits modifying an object defined with the const specifier. Your object `a` was not defined with that specifier, therefore it can be modified.

While it is true that it cannot be modified through `b`, it can be modified through other means.(like `a`).