# Why can I modify at which char const char * points?

Tags: c++, pointers, char, constants

I'm learning const and pointers playing with examples. From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949254/const-char-const-versus-const-char#4949283) I read that:
**const char* the_string** : I can change the char to which the_string points, but I cannot modify the char at which it points.

```
 int main()
{
    const char* a = "test";
    char* b = "other";
    a = b;
    cout << a << endl; //prints "other"
}
```

Why can I modify at which char **a** points ?

Comment: `a` is a pointer. It is used to refer to some data (in this case, a `char` array). Pointers are separate entities from the data they point to, so they often become a source of confusion regarding whether we're talking about the pointer or the data. In this case, `const` refers to the *data*. It doesn't have to refer to the pointer as well.

Comment: Why reopen this question? This is the exact same question as the linked question, and the linked question has good answers.

Comment: I did. @Barry you're possibly one of the smartest guys on this site, if not *the* smartest, so things that are obvious to you are possibly not to other folk. I didn't think that duplicate was "obvious" enough for a gold hammer.

Comment: @Bathsheba Ha. I don't know how to respond to that. I'm definitely not one of the smartest guys on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `a` to point at something else since `a` is itself **not** `const`: only the data to which it points is `const`.

Setting `b = a` would *not* be allowed, since you'd be *casting away* `const`.

If you want to prevent `a = b` then write

`const char* const a = "test";`