# Variable stuck into If

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, char, constants

I'm trying to learn C++ and I'm creating some useless application to test.
I'm working with `const char` and arguments, and in this code I can't get the title string.

```
const char* title = "";
if (argc >= 3) {
    string tittle(argv[2]);
    title = tittle.c_str();
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949254/const-char-const-versus-const-char

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that when you use

```
    title = tittle.c_str();
```

you are left with a dangling pointer. Instead of `const const* title`, use `std::string title`.

```
std::string title;
if (argc >= 3) {
    title = argv[2];
    cout << "true";
}
```

If you need to a `char const*` later in your program, you can use `title.c_str()`. Hopefully you won't need it.